# Can't open links to other HTML pages with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Not too sure why but I keep getting this error on my program.

```
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'login'. Did you mean 'home' instead?
```

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="uui-navbar04_menu-right">
    <div class="uui-navbar04_button-wrapper">
        <a href="{{ url_for('loginpage') }}" class="uui-button-secondary-gray-3 show-tablet w-inline-block">
          <div>Log in</div>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('loginpage') }}" class="uui-button-tertiary-gray-3 hide-tablet w-inline-block">
          <div>Log in</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="uui-button-3 w-inline-block">
          <div>Sign up</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the python:

```py
@app.route('/loginpage')
def loginpage():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Not the solution but just a tip, consider use `<form action="{{ url_for('loginpage') }}">` instead of `<a>`.

Comment: Could you share the rest of the python code?